# MySQL (MariaDB) [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb, pymysql

So, I'm struggling with mysql
I tried to use `mysql.connector`, though it turned out that it doesn't really want to cooperate when I'm connecting via `sshtunnel`
So I transfered to  `pymysql`, and here's the most basic code I was able to write:

```py
import pymysql
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder

with SSHTunnelForwarder(('192.168.0.x', 22), ssh_username='pi', ssh_password='*********', remote_bind_address=('localhost', 3306)) as tunnel:
    tunnel.start()
    mydb = pymysql.connect(host="localhost",
                                   user='Mashu',
                                   passwd='******',
                                   port=tunnel.local_bind_port,
                                   db='Special_Channels')

print(mydb)
query = "SELECT * FROM Daily"
cur = mydb.cursor()
data = cur.execute(query)
print(data)
```

Though on
`cur = mydb.cursor()`
it raises an error:

```
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

Also on a higher level it is:

```
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query ([WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine)')
```

I'm sure the database and table existst, and that this mysql account is accessible, as I have it opened and made changes to it in other software (DataGrip if anyone wonders)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest [mariadb](https://pypi.org/project/mariadb/) instead of pymysql for your case

```
pip install mariadb
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution is pretty easy.
it should all be inside `with` statement as tunnel connection (therefore database access) is closed outside statement, so it should look like this:

```
import pymysql
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder

with SSHTunnelForwarder(('192.168.0.x', 22), ssh_username='pi', ssh_password='*********', remote_bind_address=('localhost', 3306)) as tunnel:
    tunnel.start()
    mydb = pymysql.connect(host="localhost",
                                   user='Mashu',
                                   passwd='******',
                                   port=tunnel.local_bind_port,
                                   db='Special_Channels')

    print(mydb)
    query = "SELECT * FROM Daily"
    cur = mydb.cursor()
    data = cur.execute(query)
    print(data)
```